# Python next line if <! - regex mismatch

Tags: python, regex

I have a script that I am writing to parse a csv file.

If a file starts  I want to be able to move to the next text line and continue parsing.

The issue is with my regex which I cannot get to match.

```
if re.match(r'^.\<\!', line):
     line.next()
```

Example text

```
<!-- Copyright Notice: © 2010 Racing NSW (and other parties working with it). NSW racing information,including fields, form and results, is subject to copyright which is owned by Racing NSW and other parties working with it. -->

Meeting,17/02/16,CANT,Canterbury Park,Weights,TAB,+6m Entire Circuit,          ,          
Race,1,BENCHMARK 77 HANDICAP,BM77,BM77,1550,BM77      ,3U        ,~         ,HCP       ,54,0,0,17/02/2016,,          ,          ,          ,          ,BenchMark 77, Handicap, For Three-Years-Old and Upwards, No sex restriction,Of $40000. First $23025, second $7925, third $3960, fourth $1885, fifth $955, sixth $450, seventh $450, eighth $450, ninth $450, tenth $450
Horse,1,Balboa Park (NZ),0,"Gai Waterhouse",Randwick,,0,54.5,3-1-1-0 $30000.00,,0,0,0,,65.00,G,
Horse,2,Baylie Louise,0,"Matthew Dale",Canberra,,0,55,16-6-2-4 $112545.00,,0,0,0,,69.00,M,
Horse,3,Beretta,0,"Kris Lees",Broadmeadow,,0,55.5,8-2-1-1 $38305.00,,0,0,0,,66.00,G,
Horse,4,Elle Lou,0,"Chris Waller",Rosehill,,0,57.5,14-2-4-0 $141625.00,,0,0,0,,74.00,M,
Horse,5,Got Unders,0,"Ken Lantry",Broadmeadow,,0,60,33-4-9-9 $140735.00,,0,0,0,,75.00,G,
Horse,6,Lord de Air,0,"Bede Murray",Kembla Grange,,0,57,16-4-2-3 $89050.00,,0,0,0,,69.00,G,
Horse,7,Lucky Liaison,0,"Kristen Buchanan",Wyong,,0,61,49-8-6-8 $257865.00,,0,0,0,,77.00,G,
Horse,8,Makeadane,0,"John P Thompson",Randwick,,0,55,15-2-2-2 $65002.00,,0,0,0,,65.00,G,
Horse,9,Miss Denni (NZ),0,"Chris Waller",Rosehill,,0,57.5,12-2-5-1 $102075.00,,0,0,0,,74.00,M,
Horse,10,Multifacets (NZ),0,"Chris Waller",Rosehill,,0,54,6-1-0-0 $19845.00,,0,0,0,,62.00,C,
Horse,11,Mydream,0,"Melissa Harrison",Kembla Grange,,0,56.5,34-8-2-3 $142520.00,,0,0,0,,72.00,M,
Horse,12,Never Back Down,0,"Jim & Greg Lee",Randwick,,0,58,33-4-3-8 $151090.00,,0,0,0,,71.00,G,
Horse,13,Orcym Sam,0,"Gwenda Markwell",Kembla Grange,,0,59,6-3-2-0 $44350.00,,0,0,0,,73.00,G,
Horse,14,Recife Beach,0,"Kim Waugh",Wyong,,0,57,21-3-5-2 $77175.00,,0,0,0,,69.00,G,
Horse,15,Soros,0,"Joseph Pride",Warwick Farm,,0,60,36-6-2-4 $249975.00,,0,0,0,,75.00,G,
Horse,16,Spiritos,0,"Chris Waller",Rosehill,,0,55.5,8-2-0-1 $45585.00,,0,0,0,,67.00,G,
Horse,17,Ultima Chance,0,"Scott Collings",Goulburn,,0,55,39-9-6-3 $104437.00,,0,0,0,,65.00,G,
Race,2,BENCHMARK 72 HANDICAP,BM72,BM72,1250,BM72      ,3U        ,~         ,HCP       ,55.5,0,0,17/02/2016,,
```

This is full file

```
import csv
import re
from sys import argv
SCRIPT, FILENAME = argv


def out_file_name(file_name):
    """take an input file and keep the name with appended _clean"""
    file_parts = file_name.split(".",)
    output_file = file_parts[0] + '_clean.' + file_parts[1]
    return output_file


def race_table(text_file):
    """utility to reorganise poorly made csv entry"""
    output_table = []
    for line in enumerate(text_file):
        if re.match(r'^.\<\!', line):
            line.next()
        for record in text_file:
            if record[0] == 'Meeting':
                meeting = record[3]
                rail = record[6]
                weather = record[7]
                track = record[8]
            elif record[0] == 'Race':
                date = record[13]
                race = record[1]
                benchmark = record[4]
                distance = record[5]
            elif record[0] == 'Horse':
                number = record[1]
                name = record[2]
                jockey = record[6]
                barrier = record[7]
                weight = record[8]
                results = record[9]
                res_split = re.split('[- ]', results)
                starts = res_split[0]
                wins = res_split[1]
                seconds = res_split[2]
                thirds = res_split[3]
                try:
                    prizemoney = res_split[4]
                except IndexError:
                    prizemoney = 0
                trainer = record[4]
                location = record[5]
                b_rating = record[15]
                sex = record[16]
                print(name, wins, seconds)
                output_table.append((meeting, date, rail, weather, track, distance,
                                     benchmark, race, number, name, sex, b_rating,
                                     weight, barrier, starts, wins, seconds,
                                     thirds, prizemoney, trainer, location, jockey
                                     ))
        return output_table

MY_FILE = out_file_name(FILENAME)

with open(FILENAME, 'r') as f_in, open(MY_FILE, 'w') as f_out:
    CONTENT = csv.reader(f_in)
    # print(content)
    FILE_CONTENTS = race_table(CONTENT)
    # print new_name
    # f_out.write(str(FILE_CONTENTS))
    headers = ['MEETING', 'DATE', 'RAIL', 'WEATHER', 'TRACK', 'DISTANCE',
               'BENCHMARK', 'RACE', 'NUMBER', 'NAME', 'SEX', 'B_RATING',
               'WEIGHT', 'BARRIER', 'STARTS', 'WINS', 'SECONDS', 'THIRDS',
               'PRIZEMONEY', 'TRAINER', 'LOCATION', 'JOCKEY']

    f_csv = csv.writer(f_out)
    f_csv.writerow(headers)
    f_csv.writerows(FILE_CONTENTS)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot at the beginning of the expression:

```
>>> s = "<!-- Copyright Notice: © 2010 Racing NSW (and other parties working with it). NSW racing information,including fields, form and results, is subject to copyright which is owned by Racing NSW and other parties working with it. -->"
>>> 
>>> re.match(r'^.\<\!', s)
>>> re.match(r'^\<\!', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10da7fed0>
```

Alternatively, you can filter the comments earlier when initializing the `csv.reader`:

```
with open(FILENAME, 'r') as f_in, open(MY_FILE, 'w') as f_out:
    CONTENT = csv.reader(row for row in f_in if not row.startswith('<!--'))
```

Comment: like the 'not' nice and clean

Answer (score 1):

```
if re.match(r'^<!.*', line):
```

remove the `.` in front and add `.*` at end.Also there is no need to escape `<!`